# What is the chemical equation of citric acid titrated with sodium hydroxide?

Tags: acid-base, titration

What is the chemical equation of citric acid titrated with sodium hydroxide (titrant), given that the molecular formula of citric acid is

$$ \ce{C3H6O(COOH)3} $$

and the molecular formula of sodium hydroxide is

$$ NaOH $$

Citric acid being the acid and sodium hydroxide being the base

So, $$\ce{C3H6O(COOH)3 + NaOH -> ?}$$

Comment: Out of curiosity, does your source claiming "*the molecular formula of lemon is $\ce{C36H32Cl4N6O4}$*" also provides a molecular formula for, say, a cucumber, cat or a human?

Comment: i found the molecular [here](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Lemon) i am not exactly sure if its correct

Comment: That's a *pigment*, not a fruit. Also, $\ce{NaOH}$ is *not* a molecular formula, it's a formula unit. Now, what exactly you are asking about?

Comment: oh im very sorry about that, Im changing the question to ask about citric acid (as it is the main component of lemon)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reaction of citric acid [(Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citric_acid) with sodium hydroxide could be written as

$$\ce{C3H6O(COOH)3 + 3 NaOH -> 3 H2O + C3H6O(COONa)3}$$

or in the ionic form

$$\ce{C3H6O(COOH)3 + 3 OH- -> 3 H2O + C3H6O(COO)3^{3-}}$$

Comment: Lemon has no formula. Lemon is a mixture of a lot of substances. Chemically speaking, lemon is a not a pure substance. Only pure substances have formula. Lemon is like all living beings. Living beings are not pure substances. They don't have formula. They are made of cells containing a membrane, a cytoplasm, a nucleus, and many other things which are all made of a lot of different substances.